# CAMBIAR ESTILO FORMULARIO CUANDO ERROR VALIDACIÓN

Tags: javascript

Tengo que validar un formulario y cuando los campos que se rellenen sean erróneos cuando envíen el formulario tienen que ponerse los campos en rojo añadiendo una clase a mi js.

He puesto una alerta para comprobar que la validación es correcta pero no quiero que salte una alerta sino que el campo del formulario se llene en rojo con la clase .fondoRojo cuando el formulario sea erróneo.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar? ¿Cómo lo podría meter dentro de este código?

Estoy haciendo un curso y soy novata...

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
function validar() {
var nombre, partidas, expresion1;
nombre = document.getElementById("nombreJugador").value;
partidas = document.getElementById("numPartidas");
expresion1 = /[A-Za-z]{3,}/;

if (!expresion1.test(nombre)) {
alert("eeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
return false;
}

if (partidas.value <= 0) {
alert("eeeeeeeeeehhheeee");
return false;
}
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Ya tienes las clases CSS fondoRojo, puedes volver a seleccionar el elemento igual que como lo buscas inicialmente y cambiarle la clase para aplicarle esa

Comment: Para poner un fondo rojo, podrías cambiar el **alert** por ```nombre.style.backgroundColor = '#ffe6e6'``` o alternativa añadiendo una class **CSS** ```nombre.classList.add("fondoRojo")```

Answer (score 1):

al momento de obtener el input puedes añadirle la clase con el metodo .classList.add

```
function validar() {
var nombre, partidas, expresion1;
nombre = document.getElementById("nombreJugador");
partidas = document.getElementById("numPartidas");
expresion1 = /[A-Za-z]{3,}/;

if (!expresion1.test(nombre.value)) {
nombre.classList.add("fondoRojo");
return false;
}

if (partidas.value <= 0) {
alert("eeeeeeeeeehhheeee");
return false;
}
```

Comment: Así me funciona pero una vez se me pone el campo en rojo cuando los datos son incorrectos, si relleno el formulario con los datos correctos y le doy al botón de enviar formulario el rojo no me desaparece, ¿qué debería hacer?

Comment: @MiriamBeltra prueba añadirle a tu **if** un ```else { nombre.classList.remove("fondoRojo"); }``` así eliminas los estilos rojos.